# How to solve RuntimeError Trying to backward through the graph a second time in backward() function in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement a reinforcement learning agent using proximal policy optimization. However, I am getting the error

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.
```

When I search for a solution, generally it is suggested to use `retain_graph=True` as a parameter to backward function.
When, I use `retain_graph=True`, it gives another error

```
C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py:251: UserWarning: Error detected in AddmmBackward0. No forward pass information available. Enable detect anomaly during forward pass for more information. (Triggered internally at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\torch\csrc\autograd\python_anomaly_mode.cpp:97.)
  Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\RL_a\game.py", line 289, in <module>
    agent.update_policy(states, actions, rewards, log_probs, values, next_values, dones)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\RL_a\ppox.py", line 95, in update_policy
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor.py", line 492, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 251, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [128, 4096]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

My code is

````
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.distributions import Categorical
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

# Define the neural network for the policy
class PolicyNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(PolicyNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(input_size, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return torch.softmax(x, dim=-1)

# Define the Proximal Policy Optimization agent
class PPOAgent:
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, lr=1e-3, gamma=0.99, epsilon=0.2, value_coef=0.5, entropy_coef=0.01):
        self.policy = PolicyNetwork(input_size, output_size)
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.policy.parameters(), lr=lr)
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.value_coef = value_coef
        self.entropy_coef = entropy_coef

    def select_action(self, state):
        #print("state: ", state)
        xstate = torch.from_numpy(state).float()
        probs = self.policy(xstate)
        m = Categorical(probs)
        action = m.sample()
        return action.item(), m.log_prob(action)

    def update_policy(self, states, actions, rewards, log_probs, values, next_values, dones):
        torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
        returns = self.compute_returns(rewards, dones)
        """
        print("values", values, "next_values", next_values)
        print("size of values", len(values[0]), "size of next_values", len(next_values))
        print("type:",type(values[0]), type(values))
        print("returns", returns)
        print("size of returns", len(returns))
        print("type:", type(returns))
"""
        #convert values to tensor
        
        xvalues = torch.tensor(values, requires_grad=True).float()
        advantages = returns.detach() - xvalues.detach()
        print("advantages: ", advantages)
        
        loss=0
        for _ in range(ppo_epochs):
            for i in range(len(states)):
                state = torch.from_numpy(states[i]).float()
                action = torch.tensor(actions[i])
                old_log_prob = log_probs[i]
                value = xvalues.detach()[i]
                next_value = next_values[i]
                advantage = advantages.detach()[i]
                return_ = returns.detach()[i]

                # Compute the new log probability and value
                new_probs = self.policy(state)
                print("new_probs: ", new_probs)

                
                new_log_prob = torch.log(new_probs[action].clone())
                print("new_log_prob: ", new_log_prob)

                new_value = self.get_value(states[i])
                print("new_value: ", new_value)
                # Compute the surrogate loss
                ratio = torch.exp(new_log_prob - old_log_prob)
                surr1 = ratio * advantage
                surr2 = torch.clamp(ratio, 1 - self.epsilon, 1 + self.epsilon) * advantage
                policy_loss = -torch.min(surr1, surr2).mean()

                # Compute the value loss
                print("new_value: ", new_value, "return_: ", return_)
                value_loss = F.mse_loss(new_value, return_)
                #print("lennnn: ",len(new_value), len(return_), len(advantage), len(ratio), len(surr1), len(surr2), len(policy_loss), len(value_loss), len(new_probs), len(new_log_prob), len(old_log_prob), len(advantage), len(advantages), len(returns), len(xvalues), len(value), len(next_value), len(action), len(state), len(states[i]), len(states), len(actions), len(log_probs), len(values), len(next_values), len(dones))

                

                # Compute the entropy loss
                entropy_loss = -torch.sum(new_probs * torch.log(new_probs + 1e-10))

                # Total loss
                loss = policy_loss + self.value_coef * value_loss - self.entropy_coef * entropy_loss

                # Optimize the policy
                self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                print("loss: ", loss)
                #with torch.autograd.detect_anomaly():
                loss.backward()
                self.optimizer.step()

    def compute_returns(self, rewards, dones):
        returns = []
        R = 0

        for reward, done in zip(reversed(rewards), reversed(dones)):
            if done:
                R = 0
            Rz = reward + self.gamma * R
            returns.insert(0, Rz)

        returnsx = torch.tensor(returns).float()
        returnsy = (returnsx.detach() - returnsx.detach().mean()) / (returnsx.std() + 1e-8)

        return returnsy

    def get_value(self, state):
        print("ggstate: ", state)
        statex = torch.from_numpy(state).float()
        return self.policy(statex)


```
````